# Проблема с считыванием данных с ELM327

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Возможно данный вопрос здесь будет не по теме, но я уже не знаю что делать с возникшей проблемой. Бросать на пол пути не хочется.

Идея заключалась в создании блютуз устройства на ардуино для считывания данных с машины(ELM327 v2.1) используя блютуз модуль HC-05.

В данном коде происходит перевод блютуз модуля в режим MASTER и подключение к ELM327 используя его MAC адрес. Ответы модуля в коде в комментариях.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial bluetoothSerial(4, 5);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Готов)");
  bluetoothSerial.begin(38400);
  delay(1000);
  getSetAtCommand("AT");                         //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+CMODE=0");                 //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+PSWD=1234");               //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+ROLE=1");                  //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+BIND=0010,CC,4F3603");     //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+LINK=0010,CC,4F3603");     //OK
  delay(1000);
  getSetAtCommand("AT+STATE?");  // OK: CONNECTED
}

char buffer[50];
int i = 0;

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char c = Serial.read();
    if (c != '\n' && i < 49) {
      buffer[i++] = c;
    } else {
      buffer[i] = '\0';
      //Serial.println(buffer);
      getSetAtCommand(buffer);
      i = 0;
    }
  }
}

void getSetAtCommand(String command) {
  Serial.println(command);
  String added_command = command + "\r\n";
  bluetoothSerial.print(added_command);
  delay(500);
  while (bluetoothSerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(bluetoothSerial.read());
  }
}
```

Так как State возвращает CONNECTED, предполагаю что он подключился к ELM.

На команду `AT+PAIR=0010,CC,4F3603,20\r\n` модуль ничего не отвечает. На команды такие как `ATZ\r\n, AT015B\r\n, 015B\r\n, ATRV\r\n, 0105\r\n, at i\r\n, at rv\r\n, ati\r\n, atrv\r\n` модуль также ничего не отвечает. Бывает иногда отвечает ERROR[0], как понял это означает что такой команды нет.

Мне кажется что эти команды до ELM вообще не доходят. В чём может быть проблема?

Сама ELM327 работает, к телефону подключается без проблем и показывает данные.

Пробовал через симулятор на ноутбуке, подключенный блютуз модель отображается в устройствах блютуз на ноуте и так же не работает как с ELM.
Самая первая версия кода:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial bluetoothSerial(4, 5);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Готов)");
  bluetoothSerial.begin(38400);
  delay(1000);
  getSetAtCommand("AT");                         //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+CMODE=0");                 //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+PSWD=1234");               //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+ROLE=1");                  //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+BIND=0010,CC,4F3603");     //OK
  getSetAtCommand("AT+LINK=0010,CC,4F3603");     //OK
  delay(1000);
  getSetAtCommand("AT+STATE?");  // OK: CONNECTED
  delay(1000);
  getSetAtCommand("ATZ");      //нет ответа                 
  getSetAtCommand("AT015B");//нет ответа
  getSetAtCommand("015B");             //нет ответа           
  getSetAtCommand("ATRV");//нет ответа
  getSetAtCommand("0105");    //нет ответа                   
  getSetAtCommand("at i");//нет ответа
  getSetAtCommand("at rv");   //нет ответа                    
  getSetAtCommand("ati");//нет ответа
  getSetAtCommand("atrv");//нет ответа
}

void loop() {
}

void getSetAtCommand(String command) {
  Serial.println(command);
  String added_command = command + "\r\n";
  bluetoothSerial.print(added_command);
  delay(500);
  while (bluetoothSerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(bluetoothSerial.read());
  }
}
```

```
Serial.print("atsp5 )");
bluetoothSerial.print("atsp5\r\n");
delay(1000);
while (bluetoothSerial.available()) {
  Serial.write(bluetoothSerial.read());
}
```

Comment: Возможно они действительно не доходят из-за вашей функции `loop`. У вас очень странное условие окончания ввода: `if (c != '\n' && i < 49)`. Что вы хотели этим сказать? В команде не должно быть цифр? Но допустим у нас оно сработало. Что вы делаете дальше? Приписываете нуль-терминатор? Допустим. Но дальше вы используете какой-то особый класс `String`, причём тип `char[]` приводится к типу `String`. Потом вы добавляете в конец строки символы `\r\n`. Вы уверены, что они добавятся не *после* символа `\0`? Воспользуйтесь отладчиком, пройдите программу по шагам, и вы найдёте ответы на эти вопросы.

Comment: @maestro в ```loop``` находится код который принимает с терминала команду которую ввожу, и отправляет его в метод ```getSetAtCommand()```. Если отправлять стандартные команды ```AT, AT+STATE?```, и т.д. ответ от модуля приходит. Получается функция ```getSetAtCommand()``` и код в ```loop``` отрабатывают правильно.

Comment: `getSetAtCommand`, наверное, правильно. А вот `loop` - точно неправильно. Проверьте условие, которое я указал. При вводе команды `AT+PAIR=0010,CC,4F3603,20\r\n` на вход функции `getSetAtCommand` попадёт не то, что вы ожидаете.

Comment: @maestro ранее я все эти команды высылал так же как сверху в методе ```setup``` в метод ```getSetAtCommand```. Ответ так же не приходил. До этого кода в ```loop``` вообще не было. Сейчас добавлю как было.

Comment: @maestro добавил в самый конец, так же пытался сам лично отапрвлять без функций, тоже прикреплю выше

Comment: `bluetoothSerial.begin(38400);` - ¿Откуда взялось волшебное число в скобках?

Comment: @user7860670 это скорость передачи данных ELM327: 9600 или 38400 кбит/с. Я пробывал и с 9600, тоже не помогло. Также менял внутри самого модуля командой ```AT+UART=9600,0,0```

Comment: Бит/с, а не кбит/с. Если меняли скорость, то уверены, что она там не сохранилась в ПЗУ? Действительно ли сейчас нужно подключаться со скоростью 38400, а не 9600?

Comment: @maestro когда с помощью AT команды меняю у модуля, он сохранаяется в его памяти. я пробывал ставить в самом модуле 9600 и в коде 9600, так же и с 38400. Так же пробовал и в разных комбинациях, к примеру в модуле 9600, а в коде 38400 и наобарот. Результат тот же

Comment: Результат не может быть тот же. Если стороны обмена данными по UART работают на разных скоростях, то у вас на первой же команде всё сломается.

Comment: @maestro ну в коде ничего не сломается

Comment: Стало быть, в первоначальном варианте кода все команды до `AT+STATE?` включительно выполняются номально. После этой команды вы пытаетесь выполнять команды `AT+PAIR=0010,CC,4F3603,20\r\n`, `ATZ\r\n`, `AT015B\r\n`, `015B\r\n`, `ATRV\r\n`, `0105\r\n`, `at i\r\n`, `at rv\r\n`, `ati\r\n`, `atrv\r\n`, и на них ответа не приходит. Если же после команды `AT+STATE?` выполнить любую команду из тех, что была выполнена ранее, в том числе ту же самую команду, то ответ приходит. Напрашивается вывод: эти команды невалидны?

Comment: @maestro возможно они не валидны. я все такие проектны посмотрел и у всех такие команды используются и даташите для elm такие же команды расписаны. Мне кажется что их блютуз вообще не отправляет на elm, а принимает только свои команды. Может что то надо сделать чтобы он их перенаправлял на elm, или может команду в каком то другом формате высылать надо(я пробывал некоторые варианты, к примеру ```ATZ\r, ATZ```. Резултат практически такой же, иногда получал ERROR[0]).

Comment: А ваш bluetooth модуль случайно не управляется посредством AT-команд? Может на эти команды вам модуль отвечает, а не ELM?

Comment: Собственно, вы говорили, что меняли скорость командой `AT+UART=9600,0,0`. Это какую скорость вы поменяли: между Arduino и Bluetooth модулем или между Bluetooth модулем и ELM?

Comment: @maestro модуль hc-05 при включении мной в ручную переводится в режим работы с AT командами, удерживая кнопку на плате. 2 вопрос не совсем понял. А вот про это(Это какую скорость вы поменяли) не задумывался, даже не знаю что он меняет. Сейчас прочитаю

Comment: @maestro в интернете пищут что команда ```AT+UART``` меняет скорость между блютуз модулем и подключенным к нему устройством(в нашем случае ELM)

Comment: Попробуйте после команды `AT+STATE?` выполнить команду `AT+RESET`, подождать полсекунды и дальше посылать команды к ELM. Кнопку не нажимать.

Comment: @maestro так пробывал, модуль просто выйдет из режима AT команд и отключится от ELM. Сам не подключится больше, придется еще раз вводить те команды подключения

Comment: Попробуйте следующую последовательность команд: AT+RMAAD; AT+BIND...; AT+CMODE=0; AT+ROLE=1; AT+PWSD...; AT+PAIR...; AT+RESET. Затем посылайте команды в ELM.

Comment: на команды AT+RMAAD и AT+PAIR модуль ответ не присылал

Comment: в данном сайте https://wiki.iarduino.ru/page/at-komandy-bluetooth-hc-05/ есть все команды. я не пойму чем отличается команда ```AT+PAIR от AT+LINK```, тоесть "Создать пару с Bluetooth устройством" и "Подключиться к Bluetooth устройству". зачем нужна PAIR если пару мы создали уже с помощью ```AT+BIND```

Comment: https://www.drive2.ru/b/465048614524158657 Как я понял, PAIR делает сопряжение устройств (просто добавляет в список подключённых), а LINK выходит из режима AT-команд, чтобы можно было посылать команды подключённому устройству. Я потому и просил раньше команду RESET выполнить, что пытался понять, как выйти из режима AT-команд.

Comment: "Если присутствует команда AT+LINK=6635,56,7890AB, то через несколько секунд модуль выходит из режима AT и при нажатой кнопке…" - как я понимаю, фактически подключение и выход из режима команд происходит не сразу, а через несколько секунд. Поэтому на команду STATE вам отвечает HC-05, а на последующие команды - никто. Так как соединение ещё не выполнено.

Comment: @maestro у меня тоже было такое предположение, поэтому я после подключения ставил большие задержки 3,5,10 секунд. Результат был таким же. То что написано после AT+LINK модуль остаётся в режиме AT команд, а не выходит из него, в моем случае. Получается если я вас правильно понял, модуль должен выйти из режима AT команд после подключения? И потом только отправлять команды?

Comment: Когда модуль находится в режиме AT-команд, он самостоятельно обрабатывает все поступающие команды, и не отправляет их подключённым устройствам. Получается, что он пытается обработать команды, которые предназначены для ELM. Да, он должен выйти из этого режима, чтобы мог пересылать данные подключённому устройству.

Comment: @maestro теперь понял свою ошибку. Сегодня вечером проверю. Но есть одно но, после того как я писал Reset, модуль выходил из режима AT команд, и обратно не подключался к ELM. Если представим что он подключился, то мне получается надо будет в таком же виде отправлять AT команды, ATZ\r\n? Elm получается тоже находится в режиме AT команд, да ведь?

Comment: Вот уж в каком режиме находится ELM - это я не смотрел. Вы же сами сказали, что эти команды перечислены в его даташите. Вот там и смотрите, бывает ли у него вообще какой-то режим, кроме AT.

Comment: @maestro хорошо, спасибо! Отпишусь когда проверю

Comment: @maestro вы были полностью правы. Команда ```AT+RESET``` после ```AT+LINK``` помогла. Теперь команды доходят до ELM и ответ приходит.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146764/discussion-between-gfd2-and-maestro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас Bluetooth-модуль управляется посредством AT-команд, и ELM тоже управляется ими же. Поэтому нужно чётко различать, кому предназначена та или иная команда. При включении устройства вы переводите Bluetooth-модуль в режим конфигурирования кнопкой. С этого момента он начинает слушать поступающие AT-команды и обрабатывать их. **Подключённым устройствам он ничего не передаёт.**

Как только вы закончили конфигурирование Bluetooth-модуля и установили соединение с подключённым устройством, необходимо перевести Bluetooth-модуль в обычный режим, для того, чтобы он перестал обрабатывать поступающие команды, и начал пересылать их подключённому устройству. Для этого выполните после `AT+LINK` команду `AT+RESET`.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!